# Pandas Time Index pick largest number/last number on given day

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, dataframe, anaconda

I have a Pandas DataFrame object that looks something like this:

```
 'Thing 1':           Actual           Predicted        Error
 Date                                                        
 2014-09-15           140.00            0.000000   140.000000
 2014-09-15           358.03          127.738344   230.291656
 2014-09-16           373.04          326.672566    46.367434
 2014-09-17           427.99          340.367941    87.622059
 2014-09-18           484.87          390.505241    94.364759
 2014-09-18           488.22          442.403505    45.816495
 2014-09-18           491.57          445.460101    46.109899
 2014-09-29           553.37          448.516697   104.853303
 2014-09-29          1329.07          504.904052   824.165948
 2014-10-01          1200.00         1212.665718    12.665718
 2014-10-01          1289.78         1094.900089   194.879911
 2014-10-07          1314.78         1176.816864   137.963136
```

I would like to remove duplicate entries for the same day and pick the highest value for a given day.  In other words, I want something like this:

```
 'Thing 1':           Actual           Predicted        Error
 Date                                                        
 2014-09-15           358.03          127.738344   230.291656
 2014-09-16           373.04          326.672566    46.367434
 2014-09-17           427.99          340.367941    87.622059
 2014-09-18           491.57          445.460101    46.109899
 2014-09-29          1329.07          504.904052   824.165948
 2014-10-01          1289.78         1094.900089   194.879911
 2014-10-07          1314.78         1176.816864   137.963136
```

Essentially, because of how the DataFrame object was create, I always keep the last entry for a given day and discard any others.

Any ideas, my mind is totally fried from a day of coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `group by` with `agg`. `Agg` takes a dictionary of functions. As in each group the highest observation is the last one you can use the `last` function:

```
df.groupby('Date').agg({'Actual':'last','Predicted':'last','Error':'last'})
```

This returns:

```
               Actual      Predicted        Error
 Date           
 2014-09-15     358.03      127.738344      230.291656
 2014-09-16     373.04      326.672566      46.367434
 2014-09-17     427.99      340.367941      87.622059
 2014-09-18     491.57      445.460101      46.109899
 2014-09-29     1329.07     504.904052      824.165948
 2014-10-01     1289.78     1094.900089     194.879911
 2014-10-07     1314.78     1176.816864     137.963136
```